# How to generate a log file names with sequence numbers?

Tags: c

I want to dump the logs into a log file. After the max size limit of the file is reached I want to rename the file with a number ( format will be like log.%d).

There is a limit to the number of backup log files.
after the limit is reached I have to delete the oldest created log file too.

```
void log_msg( )
{
    char log_message[256];
    time_t curr_time;
    struct tm * time_info;
    int ret;
    char NewLogFileName[40];
    char oldLogFileName[40];
    struct stat sb;
    int logNum = 0;

    time( &curr_time );
    time_info = localtime(&curr_time);
    strftime(log_message, sizeof(log_message), "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S,", time_info);


     if ( files_in_Dir() > LOG_MAX_NUM_FILES  ) {
    /* delete the last created file and rename other files accordingly
      ex: file.0 -> file.1, file.1 -> file.2 */
     sprintf(oldLogFileName, "%s/%s.%d", LOG_DIR, logBaseFileName, (LOG_MAX_NUM_FILES - 1));
     unlink (oldLogFileName);

     for(logNum = 0; logNum < LOG_MAX_NUM_FILES - 1; logNum++ ) {
      sprintf(oldLogFileName, "%s/%s.%d", LOG_DIR ,logBaseFileName ,logNum);
      sprintf(NewLogFileName, "%s/%s.%d", LOG_DIR ,logBaseFileName ,logNum+1);
      if (rename(oldLogFileName,NewLogFileName) == 0) {
          printf("%s: Moved the content of %s to %s \n", __FUNCTION__, oldLogFileName, NewLogFileName);
      }else{
          printf("%s: Can't move the content of %s to %s %s \n", __FUNCTION__, oldLogFileName, NewLogFileName, strerror(errno));
      }
    }
  }

 // check for the file size before every write
    if ((stat(logFileName, &sb) == 0) && (sb.st_size > LOG_FILE_SIZE)) {
     // close the file
      close(data_log_fd);
         data_log_fd = 0;
       for(logNum = 0; logNum < LOG_MAX_NUM_FILES - 1; logNum++ ) {
      sprintf(oldLogFileName, "%s/%s.%d", LOG_DIR ,logBaseFileName ,logNum);
      sprintf(NewLogFileName, "%s/%s.%d", LOG_DIR ,logBaseFileName ,logNum+1);
      if (rename(oldLogFileName,NewLogFileName) == 0) {
          printf("%s: Moved the content of %s to %s \n", __FUNCTION__, oldLogFileName, NewLogFileName);
      }else{
          printf("%s: Can't move the content of %s to %s %s \n", __FUNCTION__, oldLogFileName, NewLogFileName, strerror(errno));
      }
    }
    
     // reinitiate logging
      data_log_init();
  }

    strcat(log_message, cpu_data);

    /** Finally write the log message to the log file */
   if( data_log_fd > 0 )
        ret = write( data_log_fd, (const void*) log_message, strlen(log_message) );
    else
        printf("Could not write data to the log file: %s\n", strerror(errno) );

  return;

}
```

There was some error in renaming, it is renaming the file log.0 to log.4 directly. No intermediate files are getting generated.

Comment: Instead of renaming, why not create the file with the correct filename.  You can the close that file and  create a new file with the correct filename.

Comment: I can't use any global variable to keep track of the sequence number of the log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Unrelated note:** The current file seems to be open when you call this function. It might get closed, without opening a new file again.*

Your renaming loop runs in this sequence:

- file.0 -> file.1
- file.1 -> file.2
- ...
- file.n-1 -> file.n

See the pattern? If `LOG_MAX_NUM_FILES` is "4", the remaining file is "file.4", renamed from "file.0" through the whole chain.

Possible solution: Run the loop with decrementing index.

Comment: You're welcome. ;-) Marking the answer is the usual way to say "thank you."